# Getting parts of a string into a collection

Tags: c#

I have a sql string as follows:

```
select a, b, c from test where a = s and b = 3
```

Using C# 2.0 specifically, how can I get:

a = s, b = 3

But in the form of a collection, so one member is "a = s", the other is "b = 3"?

Thanks
P.S. Table names have been changed but the point remains

EDIT: I have just realised I could get a substring from where onwards and then split it where there are commas and an and. Is there a better way?

Comment: You'll never have a where clause that has an `or` or `in` ?

Comment: I would actually. Making this much harder.. One way to go is to have a set of words that split the where conditions (Eg And), and use that to split the string into a collection.

Comment: I would take a look at this question [Parsing SQL in .NET ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net), a full grammer may be overkill, but it'll be a little more complicated than simple string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to take part of the sql query string, splitting it and storing it in a collection?

Use the built-in string functions or built a regular expression to extract them. A naive approach would be to split the sql string after 'where' and then again at each comma.

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "select a, b, c from test where a = s, b = 3"
Dim lastPArt() As String = sqlQuery.Split(New String() {"where"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1).Split(","c)
```

This only handles splitting the where conditions that are seperated by a comma. If more conditions such as "And" or "Or" should be supported then add them to the array of the second split call:

```
.Split(New String(){",", "or", "and"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptryEntries)
```

What is the purpose of isolating each of these conditions?

Comment: Its for a report viewer application where the parts of the query are split (something for the user).

Comment: be careful splitting on `,` for cases where the `where` clause has an `in` statement.  You can have something like `AND a in (1,2,3)` and splitting on comma will return garbage.

Comment: Also, commas may appear inside strings such as 'WHERE a LIKE "Test, ing"'.